# API design - new endpoint vs new microservice

Tags: api, domain-driven-design, microservices

During API design, there's always a question for a new functionality when to create a new endpoint in existing microservice and when to create a new microservice altogether.

Since, I am not a very technical person,  the development team mostly wants to create a new endpoint in existing service to save efforts and infra cost, but I want to understand what should be the design criteria for creating new microservice. What are the standards and are there any documents available for understanding this better.

Thanks

Comment: Without knowing your concrete example/scenario there is no way to tell. In general, for me it is all about context. If a new endpoint would require us to start storing/querying data which does not fall under the context of the existing service I would not want to "pollute" the existing service. If the context stays true then sure, add the endpoint. If the new endpoint causes us to now query other services to obtain data from them than that highlights a possible flaw in design. Though, as said, without knowing your exact setup and scenario it is impossible to tell in your case.

Comment: It's really hard to begin to answer the question. What is your role in relation to the developers? Are you the customer? If so, what are your criteria for success, if not to "save efforts and infra cost". If you have other priorities, you should communicate those. Are you a manager? If so, then is there a communication or trust issue? Are you a business analyst? If so, then why are you attempting to make or weigh in on technical decisions? Hopefully this helps to resolve the issue, which seems to be less technical and more of communication and expectations. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

A microservice (or any service at all) contains a bunch of endpoints that are closely related and enable the function the service is meant for. You only create separate microservice when:

1. You have distinct functionalities you want to enable around a single concept.
2. A need to replicate these functionalities across separate applications or application boundaries.
3. The functionalities can change independent of the application they are "embedded" in.